# Как вывести из AI получить SVG в Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: svg, illustrator

Дизайнер сделал иконки в SVG, при клике на нее открывается Adobe Illustrator где мне надо вытащить иконку. Если я нажимаю экспортировать как SVG то в коде SVG есть и белый фон на котором сама SVG. Раньше выделял и выбирал Файл -> Экспортировать выделенные элементы. Сейчас так же делаю , экспортирую но получаю пустую папку без SVG

Comment: Откройте SVG в Иллюстраторе и, перед экспортом, удалите объект белого фона.

Comment: Как удалить, лишь через кадрирование?

Comment: Нет, именно объект белого фона удалить (если он есть).